# Zero p-value for Dickey-Fuller test

Tags: time-series, arma, augmented-dickey-fuller

I feed sample time series data in statsmodels Dickey-Fuller test, and as a result I get exact 0 (zero) for p-value. I'm not sure how to intrepret that. I think that it doesn't imply stationarity as would non-zero value smaller then 0.05 imply, as I get strange results if I try to fit in ARMA model - prediction is constant value both for predicted value itself and confidence intervals too.

---

Edit: Results from ADF test are these:

```
Test statistic: -36.09998880430922,
p-value: 0.0,
Number of lags used: 0,
Critical values: {
    '1%': -3.4349732785563161,
    '5%': -2.8635818545830376,
    '10%': -2.567857072940785
}
```

I just realised that number of lags is 0, so that explains faulty 0 value in my case. Perhaps test can't find proper lag in interval and it reports 0. I'll try with differentiation...

Comment: You might be conflating a number of issues into one. **First**, a very low p-value of Dickey-Fuller test tells that the null hypothesis of the test is very unlikely to be correct. Since the null hypothesis stands for the correctness of a particular (integrated) model, you will reject it. It does not straightforwardly lead to accepting that the series is stationary, though. But if heuristically you would say "the series is stationary if $p-value<0.05$", then that holds for $p-value=0$, too; why wouldn't it? **Second**, what is the fitted ARMA model? What order? What are the coefficient values?